# define a class as Observable and Observer both

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

technically it seems OK to define a `Class` as both `Observable` and `Observer` using the following code:

```
public class Data extends Observable implements Observer
```

however, trying to implement it, it's not working.

```
public class Data extends Observable implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
        System.out.println("SC");        
    }

    Integer A;
    String B;
    Float C;

    public Data() {
        this.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void setA(Integer A) {
        this.A = A;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void setB(String B) {
        this.B = B;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void setC(Float C) {
        this.C = C;
        notifyObservers(this.C);
    }

}
```

with the `main` function as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Data d = new Data();
    d.setA(5);
    d.setB("Hi");
    d.setC(2.0f);
}
```

it should prints some "SC" but it's not working. Can anyone describes why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't `.setChanged()`, then `.notifyObservers()` has no effect. This is the case both if you have separate classes defining Observable and Observers, or if you have a single class, as in your example.

Try changing your setters as follows:

```
public void setC(Float C) {
  this.C = C;
  setChanged();  // <-- add this line
  notifyObservers(this.C);
}
```

From the documentation of **[`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html)**,

> `setChanged()` **Marks this Observable object as having been changed**; the `hasChanged` method will now return `true`.
>
> `notifyObservers(Object arg)` **If this object has changed, as indicated by the `hasChanged` method**, then notify all of its observers and then call the `clearChanged` method to indicate that this object has no longer changed.